# Category field description

Tags: categories, fields

Has anyone seen a plugin or a method where I can set a description for a category field?

I have a client who is uploading wrong image dimensions to the category image field. I want to suggest "please use 500x500" for example.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No add-ons I'm aware of, as most deal with the initial display of categories and groups, rather than the editing page (e.g. [Category Construct](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/category-construct)).

But you could modify the language file for the admin interface and change the title:

expressionengine/language/english/admin_content_lang.php
line 604:

```
'category_image' =>
'Category Image',

'category_img_blurb' =>
'This is an optional field that enables you to assign an image to your categories.',
```

Ignore the 'category_img_blurb' reference as it would seem that's now redundant and not used.

Or if you really want to hack it, expressionengine/views/admin/category_edit.php line 38 onwards, change to look like this:

```
<div class="category_field">
    <?=form_label(lang('category_image'), 'cat_image')?>
    <?=$cat_image?>
    <span><?=lang('category_img_blurb')?></span>
    <?php if (isset($cat_image_error) AND $cat_image_error !== ''): ?>
        <span class="notice"><?=$cat_image_error?></span>
        <br />
    <?php endif ?>
</div>
```

Added this line in: `<span><?=lang('category_img_blurb')?></span>`

**Update** - Just thought of a better way. Install [this addon](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css-js). Then add something like this to the JS:

```
$('.pageContents form .category_field label[for="cat_image"]').after('<p>Description of your category field</p>');
```

Comment: Thanks for this, could I maybe somehow override the "category_image" param in my EE config file? Your suggestion, though a good one, will just get overwritten in an update without any dev realising.

Comment: Yep - not ideal. Even a Control Panel theme doesn't overwrite the languages. Have dreamed up a better solution and edited answer.

Comment: Damnit! Well yes thank you that's a good idea I shall try that, thank you!